# using dompdf in PHPOffice/PHPWord

Tags: dompdf, phpword

There is many question about how to make PDF via dompdf in the PHPWord, but nobody solve it only replace some other method. Here is the solution:

The phpword have an old connection file to the dompdf library.
Modify the **\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Writer\PDF\DomPDF.php**

line35: `protected $includeFile = 'src/Autoloader.php';`

line52:  `$pdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();`

Do not forget to set the PDF rendering engine, before You use PDF in the IOFactory!

```
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($objReader, 'PDF');
```

Thats all folks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed in the current development version (0.14).
No need to change the source code anymore.

Comment: Yep, its true, but till the composer did not find the new code, this would be a possible solution and I did not found with google nowhere. Or at least, one solution :)

Comment: this is currently available on the dev-master version.